# Zend InputFilter:

Tags: web-services, zend-framework, swagger, zend-inputfilter

I have 2 objects $object1 and $object2.  Each object have firstname and lastname like this:

```
{
    "fistename": "string",
    "lastename": "string",
}
```

In my input of Web Service (WS), I have an array of this 2 objects:

```
[object1, $object2]
```

OR

```
[
    {
        "fistename": "string",
        "lastename": "string",
    },
    {
        "fistename": "string",
        "lastename": "string",
    }
]
```

How can I develop this with Zend InputFilter.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use \Zend\InputFilter\CollectionInputFilter.

```
$data = new \Zend\InputFilter\CollectionInputFilter();
$x->setInputFilter($data);
$this->add($x);
```

Comment: Yes answer is CollectionInputFilter. Did you resolve your problem or do you need example?